# How to execute MPI not as root when executing in /

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, mpi, cluster-computing

I am running into a few issues with the SSH and MPICH executing. From some previous questions that I asked, I was able to progress to a point where I executed the mpi_hello.c program.

For reference, I am working on following this tutorial on setting up MPICH: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MpichCluster

I created a directory in root called clusterFiles and I created a user on all of the nodes called clusterUser (clusteruser). I exported clusterFiles and I mounted clusterFiles in all of the nodes. Also, I changed ownership of clusterFiles to clusterUser on the master node. I also changed the home directory of clusterUser to be /clusterFiles.

I created an ssh key for clusterUser on the master node and I added the key to the authorized lists. I installed a keychain on the all nodes and on the master node I edited the .bashrc as specificed in the guide (I copied what was in the guide into .bashrc)

I also installed MPICH2 and GCC on all nodes.

I edited the machine file for my scpecific cluster.

However, when I go to execute the MPI hello_world.c program, this is where the errors occur.

I copied and pasted the code on the guide into a .c file and called it mpi_hello.c (This was done on the master node).

In the guide, the last part he just calls `mpicc [arguments]` and `mpiexec [arguments]`. However, when I go to call mpicc, I need to `sudo mpicc [arguments]`. Is this a problem I should be concerned with or would this be the proper way that it should it be done?

When I run mpiexec (without sudo), I recieve that following errors:

```
clusteruser@rgcluster2blade1:~$ mpiexec -n 7 -f machinefile ./mpi_hello

[mpiexec@rgcluster2blade1] HYDU_parse_hostfile (./utils/args/args.c:323): unable to open host file: machinefile

[mpiexec@rgcluster2blade1] mfile_fn (./ui/mpich/utils.c:341): error parsing hostfile

[mpiexec@rgcluster2blade1] match_arg (./utils/args/args.c:153): match handler returned error

[mpiexec@rgcluster2blade1] HYDU_parse_array (./utils/args/args.c:175): argument matching returned error

[mpiexec@rgcluster2blade1] parse_args (./ui/mpich/utils.c:1609): error parsing input array

[mpiexec@rgcluster2blade1] HYD_uii_mpx_get_parameters (./ui/mpich/utils.c:1660): unable to parse user arguments

[mpiexec@rgcluster2blade1] main (./ui/mpich/mpiexec.c:153): error parsing parameters
```

Are these files something that forgot to install? At first, I am thinking that I need sudo in front of mpiexec. So when I perform: `sudo mpiexec [arguments]` it "runs" but connects to the SSH cluster as root when I need it to connect as clusteruser.

My main concern is that he is not executing his commands as root. I am wondering if there is a step that is implied or at least there is a command that I was suppose to execute but didn't?

Also, I noticed that when I tried changing ownership of clusterFiles to clusterUser on the other nodes, I would get an operating not permitted error (I was root when I did this command). My thinking is that since I changed the ownership on the master node, it propagated to the other nodes since they have same username. So I was effectively changing the ownership to itself. Is this a correct thinking or is there more to it then that?

Edit:

From the suggestion of user Zulan, I have checked the permissions of the `machinefile` Interestingly enough, it is still set to rgcluster2blade1. I decided to run the command `sudo chown -R clusteruser /clusterFiles` in order to make all files/folders within clusterFiles to be owned by clusteruser. I have done this on the master node only. Will be checking the other nodes.

Edit 2:

Ok so after checking the rest of the cluster (I am only expermineting with 4 right now before doing the whole thing) I found that 2 of the nodes were giving permission to another user besides clusteruser. They were giving it to the user render. I attempted to perform `sudo chown command` but on both, I recieved an Operation not permitted error

Comment: Usually with NFS you should make sure the user ids and group ids are identical on all nodes. Take a look the permissions of the relevant shared folder, specially `machinefile`. Check if they are consistent across all nodes and post them here.

Comment: @Zulan Sure, I would be more theb happy to provide that. What is the console command to check the permission of the file?

Comment: You can run `ls -l` in the shared directory that contains `machinefile`. It will list the owner, group and permissions of each file. Run this on all nodes to see if it is consistent.

Comment: @Zulan ok, so on one server, machinefile is not owned by clusteruser. I have attempted to change it using sudo chown but I receive an operation not permitted error.

Comment: On NFS the user ids on all systems must be the same. If an NFS folder shows different ownerships on different systems it is an indication this is not the case. See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo#User_Permissions

Comment: @Zulan Yes, I was wondering how do I sync all of the UID manually across everything? I have been trying the command nfsidmap -c but I have not had any luck with it working

Comment: `machinefile` is only needed on the node where the `mpiexec` command is executed. It should be readable by the current user and doesn't really need to be on the shared filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as an update. Since I discovered that the GID and UID are all messed up, I decided to delete the user and create a new account. Before doing anything, I made sure to check and, if needed, change the UID and GID of the users such that they are the same on all nodes. I cannot remember the command off the top of my head. Will look for it later. Once I find it, I will update this answer.

Anftwards, I proceeded with the guide and everything worked fine.